# Is there any way to access the variable inside a function from another function within the same class in TemplateView of django

Tags: python, django

```js
$.ajax({
  'url' : '{% url 'add_question_main' %}',
  'type' : 'GET',
  'data' : {
  'num' : num
  },
  'success' : function(data) {
    if (data == "success") {
     alert('request sent!');
    }
  }
});
```

how to access the variable within a function from another function within the same class in django's TemplateView

```
class add_question_main(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'add_question_paper/index.html'


    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form = question_details_form()
        no_txt = request.GET.get('num')
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})


    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form = question_details_form(request.POST)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

I wonder how could I use the value of no_txt in function post?

Answer (score 0):

because the get function does not get called when 
a POST is issued, your best bet is to get that 
same value independently by refactoring the call 
into a helper method.

Option #1:

```
def get_no_txt(self):
    return self.request.GET.get('num')

def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    form = question_details_form()
    no_txt = self.get_no_txt()
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    form = question_details_form(request.POST)
    **no_txt = self.get_no_txt()**
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

Whether this will do what you want it to will also 
depend on your template and what data you are submitting 
with the form.  In particular, your action attribute on your
form should have the `num` query parameter in it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...Actually I've sent get request using ajax and I'm trying to get that value....actually your code in post function gives none as output while I print no_txt...any suggestion ?

Comment: Please read that last paragraph again:  In particular, your action attribute on your form should have the num query parameter in it.  If you're not passing in the query parameter, you won't get `no_txt`.

Comment: yes I do have query parameter as num any other suggestion..thanks for your suggestion